# Bootstrap nested grid alignment issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I am really perplexed about this bootstrap grid issue. From the screenshot below (source: http://uforest.org/Species/C/Callerya_atropurpurea.php). The header "References" has gone out of its grid alignment at the size of md & sm.

[image]

As you can see from the code below, the grid layout for References and the below citations are all under col-lg-12. This is nested within a column of col-md-9. "References" has instead jumped into the other col-md-3 column.

```
<!-- References -->
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h4>References</h4>
        LaFrankie JV, SJ Davies, LK Wang, SK Lee & SKY Lum. (2005) Forest Trees of Bukit Timah: Population Ecology in a Tropical Forest Fragment. Simply Green, Singapore. 178 pp.......           
        <br><br><br>
        <span style="float:right;"><small>Posted Date: 2012-11-27 / Modified Date: 2015-01-11</small></span>
 </div>
```

Does anyone know why? This layout worked for all my other 200 pages, and there are only 2 such instances.

Thanks!

[SOLVED]
Thanks to @Prince sodhi for suggesting to add the class clearfix. I added it to one of div tags housing the photos and it solved the issue.

```
<!-- Photos -->
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-portfolio">
        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../../images/callerya_atropurpurea1.jpg" alt="">
        <p><small>The leaflets are droopy, glossy, and bend upwards at the mid-ribs.</small></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 img-portfolio">
        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../../images/callerya_atropurpurea2.jpg" alt="">
        <p><small>The Purple Milletia always have a dense crown of canopy.</small></p>
        </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 img-portfolio">
        <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="../../images/callerya_atropurpurea3.jpg" alt="">
        <p><small>The purple flowers, and developing fruits at the base.</small></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add class `clearfix` to `h4` like

```
<h4 class="clearfix">References</h4>
```

tested and worked.

have fun.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work too... :( It seems like when I removed the photos, the References will display without issue. However I have some pages which have the exact same configuration of photos but no issue for those...

Comment: well, I tried... but then again... I added clearfix to the div tag at my photos and it magically pushes References down... haha...

Comment: shall mark this as correct and add an edit to my question to make it clearer... thanks for solving two of my bugs in one night ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should put those within a row. That will create the break you're looking for. So,...something like https://www.bootply.com/fBHELKjoGD

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. :( I tried pasting the original chunk of bootstrap code into bootply and it displays well there. Seems like it can't be replicated or that the images are causing the issue